# Can you retrieve nested array by name in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
(
[data] => Array
    (
        [account_id] => 1
        [description] => my asset
        [value] => Estimate
        [value_amount] => 85000
        [type] => Vehicle
        [owner] => Array
            (
                [app_id] => 123
                [percent] => 100
            )
    )
)
```

Clearly I can loop through the array and pull out the nested `owner` array that way, but is there something similar to `array_column` that will get the entire `owner` nested array without having to loop ?

Comment: you can simply do `$array['data']['owner']` and it should return you what you want

Comment: There is multi dimensional array of **data** or its an single array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the indexes, no function necessary.

`$owner = $array['data']['owner']`

or..

`$percent = $array['data']['owner']['percent']`

Comment: ouch, want to delete this :S

Answer (score 0):

In php it's call associative array which mean index will not numeric it can be anythink. 
So you can retrieve data like

`<?php echo $array['data']['owner']['app_id']; ?>`